# How to do load / stress testing for asp.net application locally?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to do testing for my application locally.

I have a 8 GB RAM pc and would like to know how many users can use my application concurrently without any problems.

How to do stress/load testing?

Comment: Are you using any Web API/ WCF services?

Comment: I am using web forms asp.net. I want to test my application locally first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurray!!

I found a great article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2019